# HP BIOS won't boot Ubuntu from CD

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I have this new HP computer that's come with FreeDOS. Booting from CD requires that I hit F3 but when I do, the CD drive is not recognized. I've confirmed that the Ubuntu 14.04 CD works on another computer — a Dell where you hit F12, select CD/DVD drive, and you're in the clear. It appears that things are not as simple with a HP.

There's also this option on the HP Computer Setup screen: `3rd Party Option ROM Management`. I tried it, observed that it's no different from F3 — I'm next presented with a screen that has "Drivers" as its header, then a "Devices List" that is empty, followed by a footer that has "Move Highlight", "Select Entry", and "Exit".

Isn't the CD/DVD drive supposed to be in the Devices List on that screen?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

With HP try to hit the ESC during startup, then select boot from CDrom with pressing the appropriate function key.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your computer is in legacy BIOS mode and won't detect the UEFI cd, or perhaps the other way around. The hotkey for the boot menu on my HP is f9, so that's worth a try. If I was you, I'd make sure that the boot list actually includes the optical drive.

Best of luck!